# Method annotated Transactional doesn't rollback when I throw an Exception?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I would like to rollback only what's done in an inner method.

Below the snippet code:

```
@Test
public void TransactionsTest() {
    Declaration declaration = declarationRepos.findOne(2l);

    declaration.setCode("1004");
    declarationRepos.save(declaration);

    try {
        persist(declaration);
    } catch (NotEnoughInformationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(declaration);
}


@Transactional(rollbackFor = NotEnoughInformationException.class)
private void persist(Declaration declaration) throws NotEnoughInformationException {
    declaration.setCode("1005");
    declarationRepos.save(declaration);

    throwExcep();
}

public void throwExcep() throws NotEnoughInformationException {
    throw new NotEnoughInformationException();
}
```

NotEnoughInformationException extends Exception.

I expect rollback the persist method when the exception is thrown, so then the code value must be "1004".

But nothing of that is happened, the insersions are commited, and the code value is "1005".

Otherwirse, when I do this :

```
@Test
@Transactional(rollbackFor = NotEnoughInformationException.class)
public void TransactionsTest() {
```

It works, but it's not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are catching the exception isn't it? Your test won't throw an exception that way.

Comment: Yeah, but it rollback when I made the Transactional annotation above TransactionsTest

Comment: Transaction rollback database ddl not object that change in method

Comment: Looking at the code the persist method is private and called internal from the caller. This will bypass any spring proxies set-up to provide the transaction behaviour. 

When applying the transaction onto the TransactionTest I believe the correct proxies are getting mapped.

You can confirm this by debugging and looking at the stack.

Comment: @Bluurr The transaction behaviour works when I apply the transaction onto the TransactionsTest, but then I can't get the code value "1004", it rollbacks the whole TransactionsTest scope.

Comment: And even by changing persist to be public, it dosn't resolve the issue.